# How to add plugin jar to the idea module classpath in gradle?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I have a gradle build file and use the idea plugin to generate my project files.

```
import comp.BuildConfigurator
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'base'
apply plugin: 'comp-gradle-plugins'

assert gradle.gradleVersion == '1.0-milestone-7'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

test {
    systemProperties = System.properties
}

idea.project {
    javaVersion = "1.6"
    downloadJavadoc = true
    downloadSources = true
}
```

What I would like to is that we use some class from our internal plugin `comp-gradle-plugins` in the build file. When I open the `build.gradle`, Intellij Idea does not recognize the class `comp.BuildConfigurator` because it is not added to the classpath. How do I make the idea plugin to add the plugin jars to the module classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the plugin Jars to the module class path won't help. To make IntelliJ aware of Gradle's build script class path, you'll have to use the Gradle import in IntelliJ 13. However, I don't know if this will work with a Gradle version as old as 1.0-milestone-7.

Comment: The gradle import requires almost the newest version of the gradle.